# TableView indexPath fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have following code to fill cells, when I go to bottom its giving fatal error. I observe it might me due to cell catch `nil` value in array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell!

    // Set text from the data model
    cell.textLabel?.text = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = textField.font

    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count;
}
```

Comment: your values array might be out of range.

Comment: Add Code of `numberOfRows` method

Comment: Are you updating the `values` array on a background thread?

Comment: check the `values` contains a string array and number of elements, put breakpoint at `numberOfRowsInSection` return statement and check how many counts it has ..`po  return values.count;`

Comment: put breakpoint in `cellForRowAt` and `po textField.font`. If this becomes `nil`  this can also cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function here, if only using one section.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count
}
```

Similar workarounds for multiple section. Just check that you never access a value from `values` which is past the `endIndex`.